# How do I ensure only single docker image is running?

Tags: docker

I'm building an application that I run in docker. I only want a single version of my application running at a given time, so I'm trying to stop the old iterations of containers as I start the new one.

```
mvn package docker:build
docker ps -q --filter ancestor="paul/my-app" | xargs docker stop
cd ./target/docker
docker build .
docker run -d paul/my-app
```

This creates the image as I expect and runs it like I want. If I run my script twice, however, I sometimes get two images running at the same time. Trying to diagnose this weirdness I ran this:

```
docker ps -a | awk '{ print $1,$2 }'
```

Now I see something I don't understand. The output of `docker ps -a` is

```
CONTAINER ID
aeb4c0486ef5 paul/my-app
b32be5e53df0 6d965c3e84f1
```

which means that I can't reliably stop containers by image name.

Can someone explain to me why the `ID` is a hash instead of `paul/my-app`?  How can I reliably ensure only one version of my image exists/is running at any given time?

Comment: If you want containers to have a unique name, use the `--name` option to docker run.  You can of course use a single image to spawn many containers, so you wouldn't expect to be able to address containers by image name.

Comment: @larsks Thanks, that helps a LOT. I've got something working now. I'll post momentarily with my working script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user `larsks` for the --name argument. I've gotten my application acting as a singleton as I develop it.

I've split this into two discrete scripts.

**run-docker.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
mvn package docker:build
./stop-docker.sh
cd ./target/docker
docker build .
docker run -d --name paul-my-app --restart unless-stopped paul/my-app
docker logs --follow paul-my-app
```

And it's counterpart

**stop-docker.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
docker stop paul-my-app || true
docker image prune -f
docker container prune -f
docker volume prune -f
docker network prune -f
docker system prune -f
```

Comment: There's really no reason for the `docker ps -a | grep paul-my-app | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs docker stop`.  You could replace that with `docker stop paul-my-app`.  I would also argue that calling all those `prune` commands after stopping your container is probably unnecessary, but it won't hurt.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The `docker ps -a ...`  monstrosity was a left-over from when I was seeing duplicate images running at the same time. The prunes are excessive, but I know I won't remember to do housekeeping on my file-system later unless I do it when I release the container I'm not using anymore.